# Unexpected IDENT_QUOTED on getDate()

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I get an UnExpected IDENT_QUOTED on the getDate(), can you see the problem?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Loading
  (
     L_Id            INT,
     PO_Id           INT NOT NULL,
     LD_Id           INT NOT NULL,
     LE_Id           INT,
     W_Id            INT NOT NULL,
     RemainingWieght DOUBLE,
     ExpectedStart   DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
     ExpectedEnd     TIMESTAMP,
     LoadingStatus   ENUM('ASSIGNED', 'IN_PROCESS', 'STOPPED', 'COMPLETED'),
     PRIMARY KEY (L_Id),
     FOREIGN KEY (`PO_Id`) REFERENCES `PartOder` (`PO_Id`),
     FOREIGN KEY (`LD_Id`) REFERENCES `LoadingDock` (`LD_Id`),
     FOREIGN KEY (`LE_Id`) REFERENCES `LoadingError` (`LE_Id`),
     FOREIGN KEY (`W_Id`) REFERENCES `Weighing` (`W_Id`)
  );
```

Comment: What flavour of SQL? MS, Oracle etc.

Comment: You've tried removing everything from the `CREATE TABLE` statement apart from the definition of the ExpectedStart column haven't you? The problem didn't go away when you did, did it?

Comment: `GETDATE()` is a TSQL function and seems you aren't using SQL Server or Sybase.

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL getDate() is non-deterministic

I think this may mean that you should add the constraint as a separate statement:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_MyTable_MyColumn
DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR MyColumn
```

But this is a bit of a guess... It also has the advantage of naming the constraint...

HTH

Comment: Don't think the OP is actually using SQL Server. That seems like a MySQL error message. `ExpectedStart   DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),` is fine in SQL Server anyway.